# Periodically sync Google Calendar with my app with just an initial user permission

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, calendar, backend, google-calendar-api

Within my application, there is a calendar module where the user can create events within their calendar. I would like to synchronize it with Google by sending and receiving events.

To receive events, I found a viable solution using web hooks. I make a request just once using the user's token (https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push#making-watch-requests), and my application starts receiving event notifications without needing re-authentication every time.

However, for sending events, I haven't found any other way that doesn't require the user to log in every time to validate the token. This results in a terrible user experience, with constant authentication needed for their interactions.

Is there any alternative available?

Comment: Do you use OAuth2?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion that you may consider is to use Persistent Storage to avoid re-authentication every time the application runs. Using Persistent Storage, you can save access and refresh tokens such as databases and file system. You may check this post from [imtaher](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Cloud-Hub/Access-token-expiration-time/m-p/529757) for reference.